# Arrow Function Created In An Object Returns undefined When Called Using .call() Method

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

i just created an object with an arrow function :

```
const user={
    fName:"0xN1nja",
    about:()=>{
        return this.fName;
    }
}
```

now, when i call that arrow function with .call() method, it returns undefined :

```
a=user.about.call(user);
console.log(a);
```

```
>>> undefined
```

But when i replaced that arrow function with a normal function expression, it returns the value

```
const user={
    fName:"0xN1nja",
    about:function(){
        return this.fName;
    }
}
a=user.about.call(user2);
console.log(a);
```

```
>>> 0xN1nja
```

what is happening here?

PS : im new to javascript

Comment: Google for `js arrow functions`, the first output is: Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or super, and should not be used as methods. In your case, you used an arrow function as a method. You can read about it at the top https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Don't use arrow functions as object methods.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): "Arrow functions aren't suitable for `call`, `apply` and `bind` methods, which generally rely on establishing a scope."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions don't bind to `this` as `function` do. That's one of the main reason they were introduced (probably the most important one).

You cannot even `bind` them.

Comment: "*Arrow functions don't bind to this as function do*" regular functions don't bind to `this` at all. The value for `this` is determined at call time. The `.bind()` can "set it" but it can also set any other parameters since it does partial application. Thus hinting at the true nature of `this` - it's a hidden argument to the function implicitly passed at call time.